# How to remove an error Discrete value in the chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  time = as.POSIXct(c("2021-05-04 01:00:00", "2021-05-04 02:00:00",
                           "2021-05-04 03:00:00", "2021-05-04 04:00:00", "2021-05-04 05:00:00",
                           "2021-05-04 06:00:00", "2021-05-04 07:00:00", "2021-05-04 08:00:00")),
  lng = c(15.363, 15.363, 15.363, 15.363 , 15.363, 15.363, 15.363, 15.363),
lat = c(51.232, 51.232, 51.232, 51.232, 51.232, 51.232, 51.232, 51.232),
name = c('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh'),
intensity = c(0, 7, 20, 200, 500, 500, 600, 800))

przedzialy <- seq(0, 1200, length.out=9)

df1_new <- df1 %>%
  mutate(zakresy = cut(intensity, breaks = przedzialy))

paleta_rgb <- c("#41786E", "#5AA03C", "#BED200", "#FFFA78", "#FCDC00",
                "#F5BE00", "#F0A04B", "#E68246", "#E15F32", "#D2412D")

# intensity
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df1_new, aes(lng, lat, color = zakresy), alpha = 0.5, show.legend = TRUE, size = 2) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = paleta_rgb) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void()
```

I am getting this error:
Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Additionally, I don't know how to set the range for intensity to 0, currently I have NA and I would like to get ranges for the scale:
equal to 0
(0; 100>
(100; 200>
...
(1100; 1200>

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `scale_color_gradientn` is a continuous color scale while your variable is discrete. Maybe you want `scale_color_manual(values = paleta_rgb)`?

Comment: It got better. :)
And how to deal with the scale for the value 0?
Now I have NA

Comment: Try with `cut(intensity, breaks = przedzialy, include.lowest = TRUE)` to include 0 in the first interval.

Comment: For a larger dataframe I get the message: Removed 1122 rows containing missing values (geom_point).